# Combination lock code

Tags: java, bluej

I'm trying to solve the old combination lock program. The question is below. I've wrote some code, but so far it only prints a bunch of possible combinations that always contain the first number having 36. I'm honestly super confused as to where to get it to where it needs to be.

"Imagine you need to open a standard combination dial lock but don't know the combination and don't have a pair of bolt cutters. Write a Java program in BlueJ with a method that prints all possible combinations so you can print them on a piece of paper and check off each one as you try it. Assume the numbers on each dial range from zero to thirty-six and three numbers in sequence are needed to open the lock. Suppose the lock isn't a very good one and any number that's no more than two away from the correct number in each digit will also work.  In other words if the combination is 17-6-32, then 18-5-31, 19-4-32, 15-8-33 and many other combinations will also open the lock.  Write another method that prints out a minimal list of combinations you would need to try to guarantee opening the lock. "

```
     /**
     * A method that prints all possible combinations of the lock.
     */
    public void combination(int combo)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        a = 0;
        while (a <= 36)
                {b = 0;
                while (b <= 36)
                    {c = 0;
                    while (c <= 36)
                    {
                        System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
                        c = c + 1;
                    }
                    b = b + 1;
                }
                a = a + 1;
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking that a while loop is the problem for the 36 always being in the first digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program works fine. My guess is what is happening is that BlueJ limits the consol size. Go to `Options` and turn on `Unlimited Buffering`. This should allow you to see all possible combinations. If you debug it and step through it line by line you see that all combinations are being outputted but because of the limit on how many lines are displayed it appears as if the first number is always 36 because you only get the last so many lines.

Side note: You never use the int combo parameter you pass to combinations() so if I were you I would just remove it.

Comment: Im still completely puzzled by the last bit though. "Write another method that prints out a minimal list of combinations you would need to try to guarantee opening the lock. "

Comment: Sorry, i dont fully understand... most likely because i've been studying hard all day :/ 

I've completed the 2nd part, with all combinations within 2 digits of the combination, my changing the starting value to 2, and the added value to ++3;. I'm just racking my brain trying to think of a method to print out a minimalist list of combinations.

Comment: I think this is why i may be confused. haha
It says to create one more method after the two away from one. "Write another method that prints out a minimal list of combinations you would need to try to guarantee opening the lock. "

Comment: Correct. And now i need a third method that will print out a minimalist list. Im trying to figure it out, but now im starting to think its a pointless question, considering the other 2 methods.

Comment: Alright, i guess i was confusing myself hahah. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. Still so new to programming, but it is so fun!